# How to integrate keyword search function with web browser on iOS?

Tags: ios, search, keyword

There is a custom web browser in our app. We want to show keyword suggestions when user input some words in search field. Is there some Google api for this?

I've found the similar api of Baidu:

https://m.baidu.com/su?&from=wise_web&action=opensearch&ie=utf-8&wd=keyword.
This api will return a response in json format.

How about Bing and Yahoo? Do they have some kind of keyword suggestion api?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now , **Google\Bing\Yahoo** do not offer keyword research api. The keyword planner of Google or the keyword research of Bing are just tools for a company to find which keyword is more valuable for their Ads.

We can get keyword research api from some other websites, such as https://keywordtool.io/google-suggest , but it is not free.

Here is want I found:

https://keywordtool.io/google-suggest : Google does not want people to programmatically pull its autocomplete keyword suggestions.

https://www.quora.com/Does-Yahoo-or-Bing-offer-a-keyword-research-API-similar-to-Googles-Adwords-API : No API for keyword research from Yahoo! or Bing.

Hoping this answer will help someone else.